# Santoku knife from Victorinox vs Kasumi

Tags: equipment, knives

Is there any significant difference between santoku knife from e.g. Victorinox versus santoku knife from e.g. Kasumi?

Can I as normal kitchen user :) be able to distinguish the difference between santoku knife from Victorinox, and a knife from Kasumi, which has damascus steel and costs almost 3x as mutch as the knife from Victorinox? Is the quality worth the money, or can the much cheaper Victorinox do the same for me?

[Kasumi](https://www.knivesfromjapan.co.uk/knives-c1/chefs-knives-c3/kasumi-damascus-japanese-18cm-chefs-knife-p204)

[Victorinox](https://www.victorinox.com/global/en/Products/Cutlery/Chefs-Knives/SwissClassic-Santoku-Knife-fluted-edge/p/6.8523.17B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normal user, probably not.

One of the thing that you might find better on the Japanese knife is that the blade will hold its sharpness better.

The price difference is due construction, both from the blade and the handle

Is it worth 3 times the cost ? only you can decide.

Answer (score 4):

As a former line cook, I can say that many people I've worked with *prefer* Victorinox knives at work because:

- The non-slip NSF listed & approved handles are a great plus
- They sharpen easily and hold an edge well
- They perform well in demanding, commercial applications
- They don't cost a fortune to replace when someone 'permanently borrows' one, or uses your knife to do something they would rather not use their own to do (this is more common than it probably should be)

I've owned many of both kinds, and honestly, I only use my expensive knives at home.

There's more *practical* reasons to go with a less expensive brand that maintains a very positive review average over a very expensive brand, but it's your choice and your money :)

I *personally* save the big bucks for *vintage* knives that have gone up in value consistently over the years, especially given how mass production obviates eventual rarity. So if you want to go expensive and have it last as an heirloom, go rare, too.

Otherwise, the 'house knives' from any commissary supply chain are great, and many feature Victorinox. Sure, I'd *love* to use a Shun, but my 10" Mercer Culinary gyuto holds a nice edge, too, and the resin / santoprene handle makes me *much* more confident with fish.

This holds a little *less* true with breaking knives (or Deba), or those that are engineered to take abuse, you can end up ultimately replacing cheap blades so often that you ended up spending the same anyway. But that's another situation entirely, and worth different consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well! Now I started to think about Victorinox more seriously.